# Python Flask, Error "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating an exercise app where it shows different exercises associated with different muscle groups.
On the page where I add exercises, I would like to sort exercises from my database using muscle groups.
However, when I run the app and select the Edit exercise page I get "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'" error

routes.py

```
@exercises.route('/eex', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@exercises.route('/eex/<mg>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def eex(mg=None):
    ex = Exercises.query.order_by(Exercises.name.asc())
    mgroup = [mg.group for mg in Musclegroup.query.all()]
    if mg is not None:
        ex = [e.ex.order_by(Exercises.name.asc()) for e in Musclegroup.query.filter_by(group=mg)][0]

    form = AddExerciseForm()
    form.musclegroup_id.choices = [(m.id, m.group.title()) for m in Musclegroup.query.all()]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        image_file1 = save_picture(form.image1.data)
        image_file2 = save_picture(form.image2.data)
        ex = Exercises(
            name=form.name.data,
            image1=image_file1,
            image2=image_file2,
            details=form.details.data,
            musclegroup_id=form.musclegroup_id.data
            )
        db.session.add(ex)
        db.session.flush()
        new_id = ex.id
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Exercise successfully added' 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('exercises.eex'))
    return render_template('exercises/eex.html', title='Edit Exercises', ex=ex, mgroup=mgroup, form=form)
```

Html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <!-- Search Widget -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><b>Muscle Groups</b></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{{ url_for('exercises.eex') }}">All</a>
        </li>
        {% for group in mgroup %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{{ url_for('exercises.eex', mg=group) }}">{{ group.name() }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely cause is that

```
mgroup = [mg.group for mg in Musclegroup.query.all()]
```

is giving you a list of strings (assuming `.group` is a string). Then, the template does

```
{% for group in mygroup %}
    {{ group.name }}
```

giving you the error you're seeing. The quick fix (or verification that that's the problem) is to remove that `.name`.